# Render in Viewport looks completely different from Final Render

Tags: rendering, particles, color

This is what my model looks like in the program at 32 samples.

[image]

This is what it looks like at 256 samples when rendering.

[image]

I tried setting everything to shade smooth (which it already was), but the seams do not dissappear. The crystals inside the liquid are yellow, however it seems that in the Final Render they somehow emit their colour to such an extent that everything becomes greenish and murky. The same issue persists if the Final Render has the same amount of samples as the viewport.

Let me know what the best way to share the .blend file is if you want it.

Comment: What environment?

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Here's the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0yqbxlzojynw71/glassware.blend?dl=0

Comment: You have disable "Safekeeping" collection from viewport but not from rendering ... check Outliner ... Duplicate of this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67510/2214 @moonboots I just lost privilege to vote for my previous action :)

Comment: @vklidu thanks a lot. I actually found out about the difference about hiding from viewport and hiding from render while making a different project, but I didn't connect the dots. Am I the only one who thinks the camera icons should be enabled by default?

Comment: Yeah it is a common issue ... it seems like a challenge for UI, but I cant really think how this can be avoided for beginners ... I didnt understand your last sentence ... Camera is enabled by default ... so?

Comment: The camera icon is what represents hide in render. I don't know why this option needs to be added through the dropdown menu.